# Create a new tmpfs and mount it

Tags: filesystems, tmpfs

When i do the "df" command in my machine I can see the following:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                491520    127240    364280  26% /
```

I want to create another tmpfs. How should i do it?

I am using flash which contains my bootloader, kernel and rootfs. At which stage of booting should I make the changes so that another tmpfs is created.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a line to /etc/fstab:

```
none /mnt/mytmp tmpfs defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /ramdisk
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=100M tmpfs /ramdisk
```